# Submit my form in 2 times doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I need to submit a form with a hudge params number, and I'm not allowed to modify the maxParameterCount in my tomcat.

So I decided to cut my forms data in parts, and submit them one by one.

I try to submit the first 10 rows, and then 10 next rows and so on.

But when the form is supposed to sumbit, nothing happen, the loop continues, and finally my form is still submited with all rows...
Part of my code :

```
    var valuesOriginal = new Map();
    var valuesEdited = new Map();
    var valuesBackup = new Map();
    $.each($('#zgImport').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {

        if(field.name.substring(0,13) == "userLinesAuto"){
            valuesEdited.set(field.name, field.value);
        }else if (field.name.substring(0,17) == "userLinesOriginal"){
            valuesBackup.set(field.name, field.value);
        }else if (field.name.substring(0,9) == "userLines"){
            valuesOriginal.set(field.name, field.value);
        }

    });

    var totalRows = valuesOriginal.size;
    $('[id^="userLines"]').attr("disabled", "disabled"); // empty form from userLines

    var i =0;
    var j=0;
    var fieldsNumber = 14;
    var rowPerSubmit = 3;
    var submitNumber = Math.ceil((totalRows / fieldsNumber)/rowPerSubmit);
    var currentRowNumber =0;
    var cptAddedParams = 0;
    var mapIter = valuesOriginal.entries();
    var fieldPerSubmit = rowPerSubmit*fieldsNumber;
    var currentField;


while(j<submitNumber){ // submiting several times
        alert("new form");
        while(cptAddedParams < fieldPerSubmit){ //Add params to form
            currentField = mapIter.next().value;
            var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", currentField[0]).val(valuesOriginal.get(currentField[0]));
            $('#zgImport').append($(input));
            cptAddedParams++;
        }
        cptAddedParams =0;
        j++;
        alert("submiting");
        jQuery("#zgImport").submit(function(){
            alert("Submitted");
        }); // submiting partial form
        $('[id^="userLines"]').attr("disabled", "disabled"); // empty form from userLines
    }
```

I get the "Submitted" alert only 1 time (in my test I get 20 rows so I should have it twice), and I see in debug in my java code that the controller's method is called only 1time with all form rows.

It seems that jquery waits for the 2nd sumbit() to actually submit the form.

Comment: How is `j` and `submitNumber` declared/initialized?

Comment: And `mapIter`? Also, it's hard to diagnose the problem without understanding the structure & content of your DOM. Posting the HTML or an outline of it would be helpful. It's not clear what `[id^="userLines"]` corresponds to.

Comment: I've edited my code. My form contains many rows which are users info (name, firstname, email....) I have 3 tabs which have same structure (UserInfo, UserInfoEdited, UserInfoBackup)

Comment: [id^="userLines"] is because i need to empty the form content first, and then add only my N first rows, and so on

Comment: I see `input` elements being appended to `#zgImport`, but they are being added without any ID, so I'm not sure how that line will do anything to clear out the elements in `#zgImport`.

Comment: I think it'd be much easier for you to just submit the data directly instead of plopping things into a form. `jQuery.ajax` has the ability to specify a `data` option, do you don't need to put stuff into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just submit 1 parameter `criteria` in the uri...then that parameter is a `string` and you send a JSON object...you then deserialize it on the server side...

1 object parameter

Comment: @Lempkin literally you can have a large JSON object, there is a maximum JSON size...but if you hit that you are likely trying to send too much data.  Might need to think about how to paginate or limit it to just the data you need.

Comment: Is the JSON size max bigger than the default POST max ? Actually this form is filled with a .csv file, and i have like 700 rows with 14 cells each, that's why i reached the tomcat default POST limit